# How do I inherit a view that replaces another view?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Suppose there is a view called `a` in `module_1_view.xml` in `module_1`.
Then `a` is replaced in `module_2_view.xml` in `module_2` by redefining it.

(redefining it like this : `<record id="module_1.a" model="...">`)

Now I want to inherit `a` in `module_2` (instead of `module_1`) in `module_3`.

I've tried to do this in `module_3/module_3_view.xml`:

```
<record id="b" model="...">
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_2.a" />
</record>
```

But the system says that there is no `a` in `module_2`

So, I tried this in `module_3/module_3_view.xml`:

```
<record id="b" model="...">
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_1.a" />
</record>
```

But the system refers the `a` in the `module_1` instead.

And, I tried this one in `module_3/module_3_view.xml`:

```
<record id="b" model="...">
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_2.module_1.a" />
</record>
```

It just gives an error.

How do I inherit `a` in  `module_2`?

Comment: have you added that module in dependency ?

Comment: I have added that module, if it wasn't added, wouldn't it show errors? But instead it specifically said that `module_2` doesn't have a view with id `a`.